# initialize Laravel project for Telegram Bot with sail

Tags: php, laravel, docker, php-telegram-bot, laravel-sail

I created a project on the server using Laravel sail and I wanna use this project for Telegram Bot as a web hook. I have a domain and the domain is connected to the IP server. So far so good.

But since I just started Docker and i'm newbie, I had trouble creating ssl for the server and I don't know how to install ssl with let's encrypt or something else...

Does anyone knows where to start?
thanks

i'm newbie in docker and i wanna some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel sail is [not fit for production](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/lsf33l/is_laravel_sail_production_ready/). It's not using a production ready web server, but php's built in one. It doesn't have support for ssl certificates.

Comment: thanks, so what's your suggestion? what should i do?

Comment: @Ho3inPgmer Create a production worthy setup with a real web server. [Here](https://github.com/thomasmoors/laravel-docker) is something I made for this, it uses nginx as the webserver.